# IAP doesn't work in real WP8 store

Tags: c#, in-app-purchase, windows-phone-8

I have this code in my windows phone 8 project that tests if there is a product with the product id key.  Everything works in development when I use MockIAP, but after my app is release, I can't purchase on the online store. The game crashes.

My app is using phonegap 2.3.0 and is loaded through an iframe. It executes the buy() using a cordova plugin.

Is this how other poeple are implementing IAP for their WP8 app (i.e. Download all listing information first)?

```
    private async void buy()
        {
            ListingInformation li = await Store.CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();

            if (li.ProductListings.ContainsKey(package_id))
            {
                string pID = li.ProductListings[package_id].ProductId;
                var receipt = await Store.CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(pID, true);
                parseXML(receipt);
                prepData();
                httpPostData();
                Store.CurrentApp.ReportProductFulfillment(pID);
            }
        }
```

This is what is inputed in the app store:

- In-app product ID: pack1
- Type: Consumable
- In-app product alias: 1000 credits
- Base price: 0.99 USD
- State: Published
- Tag: No available information or nothing was provided
- Keywords: No available information or nothing was provided
- Default language: English
- Title: 100 credits
- In-app product description: No available information or nothing was provided

MORE DETAIL:

Here's the step when buy() gets executed

1. A postmessage is sent from the web app inside the iframe to the wrapper that executes the cordova plugin

   pm.bind('purchase', function(e){
               cordova.exec(app.purchase_success, app.purchase_failure, "InAppPurchase", "purchase", [e.package_id, e.user_id]) 
           }, rooturl);
2. Then I deserialize the json object into package_id and user_id variables
3. I then execute the buy();

Comment: At what exact moment does the game crash? Does your game actually open the wp store or crashes when you press buy button in your game or does the crash appear once you confirm your purchase at wp store? Also does your game handle tombstoning properly (RequestProductPurchaseAsync - launches the actual wp store and your app is tombstoned).

Comment: It crashes at the moment I press the buy button. It doesn't open the wp store (is it suppose to? because in MockIAP, it doesn't either). Googling tombstoning right now.

Comment: Yes, the method I mentioned before launches the store, which tombstones your app (while MockIAP just renders a popup). Once the store is launched your screen should look something like this: http://www.windowsphonebook.com/storage/07-In-App-Purchase.jpg?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1346693185920.

Comment: ok, yeah, it crashes before the store

Comment: Try making sure you're calling Buy from UI thread. Store.CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync used to crash for us if not called from it.

Comment: thanks @mcpunky! it works now with Beta app.  Can you post below so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @user1555300: on a completely unrelated note: what's the meaning of `package_id` in your snippet? I'm wondering in relation to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907475/what-kind-of-id-goes-into-requestproductpurchaseasync).

Comment: Hi @SevaAlekseyev, I think you found the answer.  Its is the product identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making sure you're calling Buy from UI thread. Store.CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync used to crash for us if not called from it.